# Multiple authentications for web applciation and sub site

Tags: authentication, claims-based-auth, adfs, sso

I've root site collection MainSite. Also I have another site collectionSubSite hosted on "http://MainSit/SubSite" and "http://MainSit/SubSite1".

Question: Is it possible to have Anonymous authentication for MainSite and ADFS for SubSite1 and SSO(STS) for Subsite2 within one WebApp? Or I have to use different web apps for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it s possible.

Set your web application to anonymous access and everything that goes with it.

In your sub site, break inheritance, then set up permissions accordingly using groups that are AD only.  Someone trying to access the sub-site will be prompted for credentials.

Answer (score 0):

Use different web applications (as authentication is defined at the web application level).

Comment: but i cannot make 2 web app,as the site is already live.there isnt any option ?